# How to add Movie Clips to Array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Hey everyone so I have been at this for awhile now and I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about this. So I have an array of Movie Clip Objects called`outerPlanets` and they are added to an array called `aPlanetArray` so these planets in the array are added to the stage and have spacing between them all. When the Player touches the screen the character jumps on another planet and the planets scroll down on the +y axis to keep the character positioned to the center.

I add 10 planets to the stage because for performance Issues I don't want to add a lot and lose FPS so my idea was when the array is getting low such as the planet array is <= 5 then add more planets to the top position of the last last planet. Hope I am making sense. Think of it like a stack of blocks the blocks fall down one by one and more is added to the top of them as more fall down so its never ending.

Here is how I add them to the stage:

```
//Instantiate Arrays
        aPlanetArray = new Array();

        //Numbers
        xSpacing = 100;
        ySpacing = 200;
        startPoint = new Point((stage.stageWidth / 2), (stage.stageHeight / 2) );


        addOuterPlanets();

private function addOuterPlanets():void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < nPlanets; i++)
        {
            outerPlanets = new mcOuterPlanets();
            outerPlanets.x = startPoint.x + (xSpacing * i);
            outerPlanets.y = startPoint.y - (ySpacing * i);
            stage.addChild(outerPlanets);
            aPlanetArray.push(outerPlanets);

        }
    }
```

The only thing I can come up with at the moment is this:

```
if (aPlanetArray.length <= 5)
        {
            addOuterPlanets();
        }
```

This adds a new set of planets but of course just adds them to the center of the stage and not on top of the other planets. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Current Progress:

```
private function collisionPlanetHandler():void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aPlanetArray.length; i++)
        {
            var currentPlanet:mcOuterPlanets = aPlanetArray[i];

            planetContainer.addChild(aPlanetArray[i]);

            if (character.hitTestObject(currentPlanet) && !nextlevel)
            {
                trace("HIT");
                yDown = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (currentPlanet.y - 200); //have object tween to center of stage or where was last positioned
                //tap back to false
                tap = false;
                nextlevel = true;
                if (!bNullObject)  // have null object so doesnt loop again and cause error for planet == null
                {
                    planet.destroy();
                    planet =  null;
                }
                bNullObject = true;
                planetHit = currentPlanet; // to land on correct planet
                aPlanetArray.splice(i, 1);
                randomRotation = randomNumber(1, 2);  //Stop in random rotation for next planet

                TweenLite.to(planetContainer, 2.0, { y:yDown, ease:Elastic.easeOut } );


                planetIncrement -= 300;
                addPlanet(randomNumber((stage.stageWidth/2) - 220, ((stage.stageWidth/2)) + 220), planetIncrement);

            }

        }



    }
```

Comment: try this : aPlanetArray.insertAt(aPlanetArray.length - 1 ,MovieClip);

Comment: Why not just move the planets that scroll off the bottom of the screen up to the top. Like if (planet.y > stage.stageHeight){ planet.y = -20; planet.x = random;} because even if you add only 10 at a time, what if someone plays your game for 40 minutes? There is going to be a ton of planets being calculated off screen. That could cause a slow down. You should either reuse them or remove them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**example code**

```
function gameSetup():void{
    setupUsers();
    loadSounds();
    createLevel(_level1);
    addInitialPlanets();
    addCharacter();
}

private function addInitialPlanets():void{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < nPlanets; i++){
        addPlanet(startPoint.x + xSpacing * i, startPoint.y + ySpacing * i);
    }
}

private function addPlanet(xPos:Number, yPos:Number):void{
    p = new mcOuterPlanets(); 
    // var p:mcOuterPlanets = new mcOuterPlanets(); // this is preferred method
    p.x = xPos;
    p.y = yPos;
    stage.addChild(p);
    // addChild(p); // this is preferred method
    aPlanetArray.push(p);
}
```

Now when you need to add another planet above the others do

```
addPlanet(xPos, yPos);
// where xPos is desired X and yPos is desired y
```

You see what is happening here? I'm positioning the planet by using a separate function. You can offload other tasks related to add a planet as well. Imagine something like this:

```
addPlanet(xPos, yPos, color, size, speed, ringCount);
```

Get the idea?

Also you'll want to remove the planets that are far below the player to prevent slowdown. Or you could simply move the ones far below up to the top to recycle them instead of creating new planets all the time.

Comment: Hey Neal thank you man. This looks pretty awesome. Ill try implementing it and let you know how it goes

Comment: So I understand what you are getting at the only thing I am having trouble understanding is how to use the xPos and yPos to have the new planet added on top of the other planets in the container.

Comment: You'd do something like `addPlanet(10, -40)`. That will put it at X of 10 and y of -40

Comment: I completely understand that part. I think it might be something with the container I add the planets to. When the character touches a new planet all the planets tween down and stop around +200 Pixels on y axis. Now when I call on addPlanet the planet is always positioned at the top and when the character keeps jumping on higher planets the newly added planets keep spawning in the same position and just fall down until they are off the screen. They never spawn higher than the highest planet added on stage in the container.

Comment: Right because you aren't changing the value of the y you are adding them to. The first one should be -40. The next time you call the function it maybe needs to go to -80 or something. So you can have a variable like `highestPlanet` that changes each time you add a planet up there. Then the next time you add a planet up above that make the y value be `highestPlanet - 40` so it's always 40 higher than what was before the highest.

Comment: Ohh damn. I'm an idiot. Thank you so much for putting it in perspective for me. I learned a lot from everyone especially you man. I appreciate it all and hope I wasn't a bother.

Comment: Not at all. It's fun to see it start clicking for people.

Comment: Hey Neal so you say highestPlanet - 40. How would I find that? Im having trouble because initially when I start the game I add 5 planets on the stage in the array. Now each time the character lands on one a new planet spawns using the above method. Only problem is it doesnt spawn at the end of the last planet correctly until its the actual last planet. Like when i call on the addPlanet it spawns up above but with others and doesnt start working correctly until it is the last planet. I increment the y position so it works fine except when I add more than one planet initially. Any ideas?

Comment: I posted what i have so far above if you have to to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Draft example...

@Nathan , Neal Davis is right as usual, but I'd push the Vector, then addChild at its current index... Avoid the Arrays if You can. (if the instances are made by the same Class).

```
var aPlanetArray:<Vector>.MovieClip = new <Vector>.MovieClip(10);
// or  new <Vector>.MovieClip(); if You don't want to restrict the amount of items in the Vector.
// or new <Vector>.McOuterPlanets() if McOuterPlanets is a Class.

private function addOuterPlanets():void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < nPlanets; i++){
        aPlanetArray.push(new mcOuterPlanets());
        aPlanetArray[i].x = startPoint.x + (xSpacing * i);
        aPlanetArray[i].y = startPoint.y - (ySpacing * i);
        addChild(aPlanetArray[i]);
};
```

[EDIT]

If you choose to make a Vector of MovieClip (`var aPlanetArray:<Vector>.MovieClip = new <Vector>.MovieClip(10)`),
You must use `aPlanetArray[i] as McOuterPlanets` to get the methods of
Your McOuterPlanets methods!
So, in the case of a Vector of MovieClip (aPlanetArray == .MovieClip), if You want to use the methods of McOuterPlanets methods You have to do :
`var outerP : McOuterPlanets = aPlanetArray[someIndex] as McOuterPlanets;`.
Then You may call `outerP.someMethodOfMcOuterPlanets();`

Just because McOuterPlanets extends the MovieClip Class.

Never use Vectors if You have to add different types of datas in Your Vector, use the Array Class instead.

This will works but this is tricky an total nonsense!
Example :

```
var vectorOfStrings:Vector.<String> = Vector.<String>([["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]]);
// this works and Your Vector contains only Strings so OK.
trace("");
trace("length of the Vector = " + vectorOfStrings.length);
trace("vectorOfStrings.toString() = " + vectorOfStrings.toString());
trace("vectorOfStrings[0] = " + vectorOfStrings[0]);
trace("vectorOfStrings[1] = " + vectorOfStrings[1]);

var vectorOfArrays:Vector.<Array> = Vector.<Array>([["a","b","c"],[1,2,3]]);
// this works but this is tricky an total nonsense
// use the Array Class instead!
trace("\n   NEVER DO THIS! Use the Array Class instead!");
trace(" NONSENSE!");
trace("length of the Vector = " + vectorOfArrays.length);
trace("vectorOfArrays.toString() = " + vectorOfArrays.toString());
trace("vectorOfArrays[0] = " + vectorOfArrays[0]);
trace("vectorOfArrays[1] = " + vectorOfArrays[1]);
```

[/EDIT]

I hope this may help.

Check to the reference for :

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Arrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html)

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Associative arrays, maps, and dictionaries](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/associative-arrays.html)

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Vectors and ByteArrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/vectors-and-bytearrays.html)

Comment: Thx for Your feedback @Nathan , I hope this will help.
As you can see in the links I provided If an Array is made from one kind of Class, You'd better choose a Vector to store Your instances.
The Vector assume that every instance is well typed (MovieClip, Sprite, Number, uint, String...).
This may avoid a lot of mistakes or Errors which may be difficult to debug later.
Best regards.
Nicolas

Comment: Do not forget about @NealDavis answer! Feedback is always welcome!

Comment: Hey @tatactic Thanks for all the extra information I really appreciate your time. I have to take a look at the last link when i get the time because I am not too familiar with Vectors. Ive always used Movie Clips because the timeline flexibility but I read that Vectors do help with performance and since I write for mobile, I definitely need it.

Comment: @Nathan Thank You, I was unable to write anything since I answered.
Anyway, I'm happy that Your question is marked as solved.
Best regards.

Comment: yeah it's been roughly 7 years. Is everything okay? Hope all is well.

Comment: Hum, Yeap nearly ;) Hello @Nathan 
I'm bring back to life for a while :)